# iOS How to open pdf, not from NSBundle

Tags: ios, pdf, annotations, directory, bundle

I have an app where I need to annotate a pdf.  I have been using code from [how to edit a PDF in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333710/how-to-edit-a-pdf-in-objective-c) and it's great, except the file location part.  I was getting the pdf from using

```
NSString *newFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Untitled_4" ofType:@"pdf"];
```

This was working in the Simulator, but will not work on my testing iPad.

I was getting this error:

```
CGDataConsumerCreateWithFilename: failed to open 'long boring file path' for writing: Operation not permitted.
```

I also played around with

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *newFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Untitled_4.pdf"];
```

I now understand that "You are not allowed to write to the application bundle." Thanks [The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600269/the-operation-couldnt-be-completed-operation-not-permitted)

When I later try to open the new annotated pdf it does not open correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. You guys rock!

Hopefully this will help everyone else who needs help with pdf annotations in iOS.

Comment: Did you NSLog the variable newFilePath?

Comment: Yes I did. It returned the same long string I called "long boring file path" above

Comment: Specifically, it was "/var/mobile/Applications/EFEF65E1-5D45-4720-A2D8-3B3AFE04D2E5/TeacherTableView4.app/Untitled_4.pdf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I ended up using

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *newFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Untitled_4.pdf"];
```

then drawing everything.

The problem was not there, it was getting the finished pdf later to show it. I needed to use that same code later.

Thanks for your help.

Hope anyone confused who finds this later will have their problem solved as well.